# ETL implementation using Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I need to implement an ETL application for one of the projects am working on.

It has following steps:

1. Need to read from a table to retrieve some values that will be
   passed in as Job parameters.
2. The returned object of the step 1 will be further used to retrieve
   some data from a second table.
3. Then has to read from a flat file that will be used along with the
   values from step 2. Apply the business logic. Then write to a table.

We are using Spring Data JPA, Spring integration.

The challenge I am facing is to read the values from a table to retrieve the parameters for the job then launch the job.

And then the output of step 2 has to be sent along with the File information for further processing.

I know how to implement the above steps independently but struggling to tie them from end to end.

Sharing any ideas to design the above would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you some ideas for your differents points.

**1 - Read table values and pass them as Job Parameters**

I see 2 solutions here :

You could do a "manual" query (ie. without springbatch), and then do your business logic to pass the results as JobParameters (you just need a `JobLauncher` or a `CommandLineJobRunner`, see [Springbatch Documentation §4.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html)) :

```
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job = (Job) context.getBean(jobName);

// Do your business logic and your database query here.

// Create your parameters
JobParameter parameter = new JobParameter(resultOfQuery);

// Add them to a map
Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
parameters.add("yourParameter", parameter);

// Pass them to the job
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(parameters);
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
```

The other solution would be to add a `JobExecutionListener` and override the method `beforeJob` to do your query and then save the results in the `executionContext` (which you can then access with : `#{jobExecutionContext[name]}`).

```
@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    // Do your business logic and your database query here.

    jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put(key, value);
}
```

In each case, you can use a SpringBatch `ItemReader` to do your query. You can, for example, declare an item reader as a field for your listener (don't forget the setter) and configure it as such :

```
<batch:listener>
    <bean class="xx.xx.xx.YourListener">
        <property name="reader">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
                <property name="sql" value="${yourSQL}"></property>
                 <property name="rowMapper">
                    <bean class="xx.xx.xx.YourRowMapper"></bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</batch:listener>
```

**2 - Read a table depending on results from previous step**

Once more, you can use the `JobExecutionContext` to store and retreive data between steps. You can then implement a `StepExecutionListener` to override the method `beforeStep` and access `StepExecution` which will lead you to `JobExecution`.

**3 - Send result from table reading along results of file reading**

There is no "default" `CompositeItemReader` which would let you read from 2 sources at the same time, but I don't think that's what you actually want to do.

For your case, I would declare the "table reader" as the reader in a `<batch:chunk>` and then declare a custom `ItemProcessor` which would have another `ItemReader` field. This reader would be your `FlatFileItemReader`. You can then manually start the read and apply your business logic in the `process` method.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Let me try the suggested approach and see how it goes